# Bootstrap 4 light color Overlay on top of Image to make text standout/see better

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

So i am trying to put a very light color on top of img or the parent div of the image so that what ever the image is , light or dark the text will be visible clearly without any problem. As you can see i am using bootstrap card class to have the text over image also. This is my attempt so far, but having this opacity is making the text and image dimmer, I wanted the image to be dimmer/lighter so that text is strongly visible. Whats a good solution here. I seen people using a transparent background color as image and overlaying it css, I dont know if thats a good approach

```css
.dnow-regionsContent {
    background-color: SlateGray;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.dnow-regionsContent .card-img-overlay img {
    max-height: 40rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>slick slider</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous">


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <section class="dnow-regionsWrap">
      <div class="dnow-regionsContent">
         <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
            <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-center container">
               <div class="row  mb-5">
                  <div class=" col-sm-12 text-content">
                     <h2 class="card-title ">
                        Canada
                     </h2>
                     <button class="btn btn-primary">
                        Viewl all Location
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if I understand the question, but from what i understand you want to apply an overlay color on top of the image so the image became dimmer.
If that this solution may help you
create a new div

```
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fvw247x7ml90mf/canadaN.jpg?dl=1" alt="">
<div class="overlay-div"></div> <!-- the new div -->
<div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-center container">
```

and apply some css styles

```
.overlay-div{
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:#000;
   opacity:.7;
}
```

there is a pen file you can try it [img overlay color](https://codepen.io/bechir93aa/pen/qLgXRy)